# How to improve the performance of an SQLite+UITableView app?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview

We have an app with sqlite which has morethan 10,000 rows and above 10MB

and in our first view we have two buttons
clicking on first button will take to another view which has a tableview,
we need to show all these 10,000 records in that tableview for searching.

Since we are loading all items at a time, its taking some time to load that view when clicked on button in first view.

is there any option to avoid the delay? like any lazy loading option
or showing 100-1000 rows first then appending all other rows at bottom.

**THIS IS WHAT APPLE HAS WRITTEN:**

We found the following issue with the user interface of your app:

- Your app responded very slowly. For example, when we tapped the Movies or
  Albums button, it took 5 seconds.`

Comment: Post some code on how you handle processing from the data source. UITableView usually handles your use-case very well. It is something else taking up time within your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try loading the data in multiple batches using the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses. See the sqllite [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). E.g. on page load you request the first 100 result rows and when that request completes you can request the next 100 etc.

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `tableView`, then use this code this code generate the cell using the view size. Please put that line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: That gives you a different cell for each row and completely goes against the purpose of dequeueing cells to be more efficient by reusing cells rather than creating one for each row specifically.